# Nintex Browser Control Shortened in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ssom, nintex

My Nintex form is working fine for list and document libraries ,But when my users try to browse the attachment "Browser" option is getting Truncated as below.

Can any one help me what's the issue weather it is related to CSS or Browser and how can I solve this 
[image]